# Complete the picture

Tags: cipher, visual

Below we have a set of strange squares. Try complete it!

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They should be completed like so:

> [image]

Because:

> If you rotate the image to the right, the lines form a number saying how many letters are in the color of the square. (BLUE has 4 letters; BROWN has 5 letters; and so on.)